# sparkjava routing conflict: static files and default exception handler

Tags: routes, spark-java

I have a json webservice which I want to only return json.  Right now, when a user requests a resource which doesn't exist, they get an html 404 response from sparkjava engine.

I tried returning 404 json response as follows:

1. using sparkjava, I initialize my static files.

   externalStaticFileLocation("/my/static/file/path");
2. I set up my application endpoints.
3. The last endpoints I set up are my 404 handlers.  Basically, if the URL wasn't matched by 1 or 2 above, then assume 404 like so:

   ```
   get("/*", BaseWebApp::notFound, new JsonTransformer());
   put("/*", BaseWebApp::notFound, new JsonTransformer());
   post("/*", BaseWebApp::notFound, new JsonTransformer());
   delete("/*", BaseWebApp::notFound, new JsonTransformer());
   ```

This does not work.  When I request a static file, I get my json 404 response.  The sparkjava documentation states:

```
Routes are matched in the order they are defined. The first route that 
matches the request is invoked.
```

I would have thought that since I initialized my static files before the 404 endpoints that I would not get a 404 response.  This question is similar and unfortunately is not answered: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sparkjava/static/sparkjava/2SQFmSao2t8/ucfbM-QDCaMJ.

Answer (score 0):

My web application serves static html files and it also has json webservice endpoints.  I separated out my namespace so that all json webservices are prefixed with "v1".  Now, my json 404 matches "/v1/*".  I get a json 404 when they try to request a nonexistent json endpoint.  The application returns html 404 otherwise.

This is better than what I originally had since there are cases where I should return an html 404.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you declare such a route? It would make sense only if it was a before/after filter.

Comment: I have a json web service.  Right now, if the user hits a 404, they get an HTML response which is automatically generated by sparkjava.  This will break clients of my service.  I'm sure there's other legit use cases as well ...

Comment: Ok, I see. Given this situation, I think a before filter could do the trick. You can halt(404) and put the desired content in the response body case the client had accessed a non valid route.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Can you post a working code example?

Comment: ok, I just cant do it right now, but I will, as soon as I can.

Comment: I tried the approach I told you, did not worked. Hope that somebody else is going to do the trick. I wold appreciate as well.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot.  I have an idea, which is to stream the static files myself based on the URI.  However, I'd rather not do this.  It seems like a bug in sparkjava (either documentation or the engine).